# Google Map ошибка сервисов google play AVD

Tags: android, google-maps, avd

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь запустить приложение с картами Google на эмуляторе AVD.
Приложение запускается, но вместо карт выводит сообщение об обновлении Google Play сервисов.
Искал информацию о решении данной проблемы, не нашел. 
Эмулятор запускаю выше 4.2.2, с подключенными Google Api:
[image: Список AVD, отмечен используемый]
Объясните, пожалуйста, почему возникает данная проблема.

Comment: Ну обнови сервисы

Comment: Проблема не столь банальна, как может показаться. SDK обновлен полностью

Comment: Я использовал genymotion, AVD был уг

Comment: Подключайте maps sdk прошлых версий для тестов на эмуляторе.

Comment: @eugeneek Как всегда все гениальное оказывается - простым :)  
Добавьте в качестве ответа, для отметки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, официальные AVD от Google не имеют установленного Google Play, поэтому обновление Play Services на них невозможно (или является нетривиальной задачей).

В качестве workaround можно использовать GoogleMaps SDK предыдущих версий, которые не требуют обновлённых сервисов.

Начиная с Android Studio 2.4, можно создать [AVD со встроенным Google Play](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/android-studio-24-preview-4-is-now.html). Возможно, там можно будет обновлять сервисы и данная проблема перестанет быть актуальной.